# Problemas con listas ligadas

Tags: c, funciones, punteros

Tengo un problema con listas ligadas, simplemente son nombres que se leen de un fichero, y al usar una función que tengo declarada como "**buscaNodo**", que lo unico que hace es mostrar por pantalla si ha encontrado el nombre o no

Cuando meto un nombre que no se encuentra en el fichero, no me lo muestra por pantalla, pero cuando sí esta en el fichero sí me lo muestra. He probado a hacer la función de tipo ***int*** y hacer un "***return enc***" luego en el **main** poner que si `buscaNodo ==1` entonces me muestre por pantalla que se ha encontrado el nombre, si no que me muestre lo contrario.

Si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradeceria mucho. Este es mi codigo:

```
struct Tnodo{
char nombre[46];
struct Tnodo *siguiente;
};

struct Tcabecera{
int tam;
struct Tnodo *cabecera;
};
```

---

**El main**

```
void main(){
int i=0;
FILE *f;
struct Tcabecera lista;
struct Tnodo *aux;
lista.cabecera=NULL;
lista.tam=0;

f = fopen("piloto.txt","r");

if(f==NULL){
    printf("Fichero no encontrado.\n");
}else{
    printf("Fichero encontrado.\n");
}

aux = (struct Tnodo *) malloc(sizeof(struct Tnodo));
*aux=leerDatos(f);

while(!feof(f)){
    ligarDatos(aux,&lista);
    aux = (struct Tnodo *) malloc(sizeof(struct Tnodo));
    *aux=leerDatos(f);
    lista.tam++;
}
     //printf("Tamanio: %d\n",lista.tam);
    //escribeLista(lista);
        buscaNodo(lista);
               fclose(f);
}
```

---

**Y la funcion:**

```
void buscaNodo(struct Tcabecera lista){
int enc = 0;
char nom[20];
struct Tnodo *aux;
aux=lista.cabecera;
printf("Introduce el nombre que buscas: ");
scanf("%s",&nom);
while( !enc){
    if(cadIguales(nom,aux->nombre)){
        enc=1;
    }
    aux=aux->siguiente;
    //printf("El valor de enc=%d\n",enc);
}

if(enc==1){
    printf("Nombre encontrado.\n");
}else{
    printf("Nombre no encontrado.\n");
}

}
```

---

La funcion **cadIguales** es esta por si alguien se lo pregunta:

```
int cadIguales(char cad1[],char cad2[]){
int i=0;
while(cad1[i]!='\0' && cad2[i]!='\0' && cad1[i]==cad2[i]){
    i++;
}
return cad1[i]==cad2[i];
}
```

Por favor ayuda , llevo varias horas con este problema y no se que puede estar mal.

Gracias.

Comment: Cual es el error?

Comment: @JuniorUsca Cuando no se encuntra el nombre el programa no muestra nada por pantalla y se supone que debe mostrar que no lo ha encontrado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en el `while(!enc)` ya que hasta que no encuentre la cadena seguirá intentando buscar, lo cual implica que si no existe, se quedara dentro del `while` y probablemente te mande algún error haciendo que el programa se quede allí.

Tienes que hacer que tu programa salga de ese while cuando:

- haya completado la busqueda en toda la lista, o
- cuando haya encontrado el nombre

```
void buscaNodo(struct Tcabecera lista){
  int enc = 0;
  char nom[20];
  struct Tnodo *aux;
  aux=lista.cabecera;
  printf("Introduce el nombre que buscas: ");
  scanf("%s",&nom);
  while(aux != NULL){ // con esta comparacion verificamos si ya esta al final de la lista
    if(cadIguales(nom,aux->nombre)){
      enc=1;
      break; // con un break obligamos al programa a salir del while
             // y continuar con lo que sigue despues del while
    }
    aux=aux->siguiente;
  }

  if(enc==1){
    printf("Nombre encontrado.\n");
  }else{
    printf("Nombre no encontrado.\n");
  }

}
```

Con eso debería funcionar, si no es así, lo mas seguro es que estés formando mal la lista. Si es el caso verifica esta parte de tu código:

```
while(!feof(f)){
    ligarDatos(aux,&lista);
    aux = (struct Tnodo *) malloc(sizeof(struct Tnodo));
    *aux=leerDatos(f);
    lista.tam++;
}
```